# Reading values from a plist file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextField and when the user hits a save button, the text should be saved into a plist file with the following code:

```
-(IBAction)saveButtonPressed
{
       NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"]; //3

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
        {
            //5
            NSString *bundle=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];

            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
        }
       NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
        //here add elements to data file and write data to file
        [data setObject:[inkTextField text] forKey:@"inkText"];

        BOOL didWrite=[data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
       if(didWrite==YES)
           NSLog(@"didWrite");
       else NSLog(@"nope");
        [data release];
    }
```

Then I have a UITableView and I want to load the string value of plist into the cell text field with the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellViewController"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellViewController" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"]; //3

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
    {
        //5
        NSString *bundle=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *savedInks = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

    //load from savedStock example int value
    NSString *value;
    value = [[savedInks objectForKey:@"inkText"]stringValue];
    [savedInks release];
    inkTitle.text=value;
    return cell;
}
```

When I save, I get a the log outputs didWrite, so I know it saved properly. However when I visit the tableView, I get a crash with the following error:

```
2011-08-19 13:56:45.717 MyApp[36067:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4bb5fa0'
```

So I thought it was something to do with this line:

```
value = [[savedInks objectForKey:@"inkText"]stringValue];
```

so I tried

```
value = [savedInks objectForKey:@"inkText"];
```

but that also causes a crash but with no message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the 'stringValue', as you're already returning a NSString value.

In the next line, you're releasing 'savedInks', before retaining 'value'. Swap the release with the line below it and see if that works.:

```
NSString *value;
value = [savedInks objectForKey:@"inkText"];
inkTitle.text=value;
[savedInks release];
```

When savedInks is released, all of the objects within the dictionary are released as well. Setting inkTtile.text should perform a retain on value automatically.

Comment: Thank you this worked! But doesn't `value` now hold the value that was in savedInks, so that I can release it without it affecting the value of `value`?

Comment: No - you have not retained `value`, so it will get released when the dictionary is released. Remember that `value` is just a reference to a place in memory containing the actual string. Once that release count hits zero, the memory is freed, and the pointer is invalid.

Comment: No, value is a pointer to the string that's (also) referenced from SavedInks.  SavedInks is released, all the items in the array are also released.  You would need to retain that string, or remove it from the Dictionary (and retain it).